# How to configure outlook to preserve user's profile on citrix xenapp server?

Tags: outlook, citrix

**[Citrix xenapp – Ivanti workspace – Outlook] How to configure outlook to preserve user's profile on citrix xenapp server ?**

**Context:**
We have many applications (mostly in C#) using the standard “MAPI” (interop.outlook) to open outlook and send emails.
All is fine when these apps are running on the user’s workstations.
Now we are migrating our applications into a private cloud using citrix xenapp to publish our apps on a win citrix 2012  ver 1.04 server and using Ivanti workspace control to present the virtual desktop to users.
Window user’s **profiles are systematically created/deleted** by Ivanti when user connect/disconnect from the citrix app. which forces the user to recreate his outlook profile every time he connects to the citrix app.

**Question:**
What can be done to preserve the outlook user’s profile on the citrix server in order the user can continue using outlook without having to re-create his account every time he connects (Only once would be acceptable).
Or how to connect outlook to the existing user’s profile on his LOCAL workstation (running  a powershell script on the citrix server at user’s logon for example)
In brief, how to make transparent to our migrated application (not changing sources), in order they can continue using outlook the same way as they were on user’s workstation using its existing profile ?